# Literature on a specific identification strategy (DiD)

Tags: difference-in-difference

In part of an econometric project I need to run a specific DiD. Yet I can't find specific literature related to it. I'm sure it exists similar things but I have difficulties. Maybe you could help me :)

So, to explain briefly.
I have a reform that has been experimented between 2000 and 2008 in some districts. Each year more and more schools are implementing the reform in a district. So that, students could choose between the reformed path or the "normal" one at that time: for each district, I have a intent to treat so. 
then, in 2009, all schools have to implement the reform so that every student is now treated.

I have to implement a Diff in Diff strategy that takes into account this ITT as well as the additive component.
Is someone has an idea about some papers that do that, it could be really awesome :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The best reference in causal models (like Diff-in-Diff) is the book of Angrist and Pischke, called *Mostly Harmless Econometrics: An empiricist's Companion*.

I also suggest read a article called *Water for Life: The Impact of the privatization of Water Services on Child Mortality*, it's good for get some insights related to how construct a Diff-in-Diff model and get some inspiration for do good robustness checks.

Your case is feasible for the application of a diff-in-diff. However, it is not possible to include the period where all districts were treated, I suggest you use the data before 2009.